# Using "by the time he WAS 30," when he's only 27

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

I was reading news online in the morning. I read a headline which did not make any sense to me. Because it had a grammar issue as per my opinion. But I think, as the reporter has written the headline so he must have something in his mind and headline may have been grammatically perfect.

> The headline was
>
> *Rahul was aiming to be a billionaire by the time he **was** 30*

My concern is, the boy who was mentioned by the reporter. He was 26, when he thought that he would be a billionaire when he would turn 30 and now he is 27. So why the reporter has used *was*? As per my opinion the headline should have been *Rahul was aiming to be a billionaire by the time he **would** turn 30*.

Comment: Why didn't you provide a [link](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-28001511)? And why did you feel the need to change the name from [Arjan to Rahul](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-28001511)? Have a look at [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084), and be sure to include a link next time. (Also, that's a _caption_, not a _headline_.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am so sorry as I did not mention the link. I was thinking that maybe it was not needed. But I will make sure I do it next time. Thanks for feedback as well. I appreciate your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he was not yet a billionaire, I would tend to agree with you. The caption would be improved had it read:

> Rahul **is** aiming to be a billionaire by the time he **is** 30

However, there at least two reasons we might put this in the past tense:

1. Billionaire status has been reached. Goal achieved. This whole business about setting a goal and striving to attain it is now in the past.
2. That goal is no longer Rahul's goal. Maybe he's decided to become a monk instead. Or maybe he realizes that goal is not quite realistic, and he has tempered it.

In either case, the past tense would perfectly natural:

> Rahul **was** aiming to be a billionaire by the time he **was** 30...
>
> > ... but now that he's a billionaire, he's come to realize that money can't buy happiness.
> > ... but now he's decided to pursue a calling much nobler than acquiring wealth.
> > ... but now he's setting his sights on age 32.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>the real reason for the past tense in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the boy has not achieved the target yet. I have read the complete news. So, as per the news he would get the target when he would turn 32 or so. So I think the caption was wrong, right?

Comment: The goal has been changed. That's why his former goal is referred to in the past tense.

Comment: I agree. But, maybe I am not making sense as he was never 30. So "was" is still not making sense to me.

Comment: Forget age for a minute. I have a goal to answer 1000 questions on ELL before July 1st. Oh, wait! I'm more than 300 questions away, and July 1st is right around the corner! I guess that's not realistic. Time to set a new goal. My goal **was** to answer 1000 questions by July 1st. Now my goal **is** to answer 800 questions by December 31st. As soon as my goal changes, the old goal gets referred to in the past tense. As the article says, _"**Last year**, when the economy was better, I **was** aiming to be in the billionaire club by 30 but that's going to push to 32 **now**."_